# total input/output transfer rate for some specific size for specific device

Tags: linux, command-line

i am trying to find total time taken by the system to send specific size of data to specific device using utilitys. i am using these commands IOSTAT DSTAT SAR.
those commands giving in sec wise and size wise not total size and total time

i want know total time taken by the system to send specific input/output data with specific size to specific device(using command-line)

Answer (score 0):

```
time cp $data $device
```

Look at the `sys` line.